# http live video stream not working on a html webpage

Tags: html, video, video-streaming

I have an RTSP stream coming in from an IP camera that I'm converting to an HTTP mp4 stream using VLC media player. I want to display the resulting stream in a webpage and was hoping to use the HTML5  tag to do that but it just ends up blank where another separate VLC instance is able to play the stream fine, so it is working - just not on the webpage.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Are you able to access the stream manually over the web?

Comment: Not that I've been able to so far, no. The stream is working as I've tested it with another instance of VLC, but I can't get it to play within the browser using html5. As I say any help or assistance appreciated.

Comment: I am not quite sure how VLC does streaming you might have to look into that, I also recommend looking into streaming using YouTube and then embedding a feed on your page, that's quit easy and perhaps you might be able to stream VLC to YouTube

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Live streaming in HTML5 video tag is not supported by all browsers.

This link could help you:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Audio_and_video_delivery/Live_streaming_web_audio_and_video

Comment: I would have assumed Google Chrome and Firefox were on top of this? What are the alternatives in this case then?

Comment: From my experience there isn't a widely supported alternative available yet. But you can impose restrictions on the browser to use

Comment: A nice alternative (for me) is using multipart x-mixed-replace MIME to serve a serie of JPEG images, it should be supported by many browsers but it is video-only

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using MJPEG, where you will pass each frame to html page in 'JPEG' encoded format and use mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame' in response.
You should see that the function passing the images should return multiple images to make it seem like a video. It can be done using generator in python and java. Find something which works similar to that in other languages for your application.